# converting list inside tuple and adding on to the tuple

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
[('Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'), ('ac', [2, 2]), ('hello', [4,3])]
```

how can I get: `[('Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'), ('ac', 2, 2), ('hello', 4,3)]`

so basically how to get rid of the list inside tuple!!!!

---

**`or:`**

How to convert this to `{'ac': [2, 2], 'hello': [4, 3]}` or `{'ac': (2, 2), 'hello': (4, 3)}`

to: `[('ac', 2, 2), ('hello', 4,3)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For the dictionary

- `*v` will unpack `values`

```py
y = {'ac': [2, 2], 'hello': [4, 3]}

[(k, *v) for k, v in y.items()]

>>> [('ac', 2, 2), ('hello', 4, 3)]
```

### For the list of tuples

```py
z = [('Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'), ('ac', [2, 2]), ('hello', [4,3])]

xx = list()
for x in z:
    tt = tuple()
    for y in x:
        if not type(y) == list:
            tt += (y,)
        else:
            tt += (*y,)
    xx.append(tt)

xx = [('Username', 'INFO', 'ERROR'), ('ac', 2, 2), ('hello', 4, 3)]
```

Comment: Hi, @Trenton this really helped me a lot, thank you very much. I used your concatenated version of for loop for others too and it worked like a charm!! really do appreciate it!